# Accessing $scope variable outside function in same controller angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in AngularJS and I wanted to know how I can access my `$scope` variable from outside function inside same controller. How to achieve this? Here is my code:

```
.controller('RekapCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$state', '$stateParams', '$firebaseArray', 'Alkitabdetail', function($scope, $timeout, $state, $stateParams, $firebaseArray, Alkitabdetail) {
    var rootRef = new Firebase('https://ayobacaalkitab.firebaseio.com/');
    var childUsers = rootRef.child('users');
    var childDate = rootRef.child('tanggal');
    var rekapId = $stateParams.rekapId;
    console.log(rekapId);
    childDate.child(rekapId).child('date').child('tanggalBaca').once('value', function(snap) {
      var snapshot = snap.val();
      $scope.tanggal = snapshot;
      console.log($scope.tanggal);
    })
    // here outside function i want to access my $scope.tanggal;
}])
```

**UPDATE**
What i want to achieve is i can use the result from firebase which inside $scope.tanggal to process in another function in same controller.

i tried many things including using $scope.$apply but nothing worked it's always return undefined when i am trying to console.log $scope.tanggal outside the snapshot function.

[image]

Hope this made you understand my question.

**ANSWER**

I found the answer here
[How to get variable value outside angular function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38945408/how-to-get-variable-value-outside-angular-function?rq=1)
because 'value' is async and create some delay so i came with the solution using comeback function

```
childDate.child(rekapId).child('date').child('tanggalBaca').once('value',function(snap){
        var snapshot= snap.val();
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.tanggal = snapshot;
        });
        console.log($scope.tanggal);
        myAfterFunction(); //here i call the function 
    })
function myAfterFunction(){
    console.log($scope.tanggal); // The function is triggered after called in snapshot function this time $scope.tanggal has value from firebase
    }
```

Comment: If it's not straight available with `$scope.tanggal` you should try using `$scope.apply()`function inside your function where you declare the scope variable.

Comment: your question isn't very clear;  it seems to be asking how to access a variable that should be accessible in that location, indicating that either you are receiving an error when you try it that you didn't provide, or you didn't try the solution at all.

Comment: Hi @SamuelBilly Is your post a duplicate to the one where you found the answer? If so, you can actually flag your own post as duplicate. :)

Comment: If it's not a duplicate, can you provide your solution as an answer? That is totally acceptable on StackOverflow and is clearer to future visitors than combining the answer with your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly access it, just try  `console.log($scope.tanggal);`,
If your function is not in angularjs scope, you can use `$scope.$apply`

```
childDate.child(rekapId).child('date').child('tanggalBaca').once('value',function(snap){
            var snapshot= snap.val();
     $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.tanggal = snapshot;
    });
            console.log($scope.tanggal);
        })

console.log($scope.tanggal);
```

Comment: i tried your solution. still not working console.log result undefined

Comment: what is the value for snapshot ?? can u do console.log?

Comment: The result of console.log inside function return the value "8 Sept 2016". but when i tried to console.log outside the function the result is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here 
[How to get variable value outside angular function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38945408/how-to-get-variable-value-outside-angular-function?rq=1)

because 'value' is async and create some delay so i came with the solution using comeback function

```
    childDate.child(rekapId).child('date').child('tanggalBaca').once('value',function(snap){ 
var snapshot= snap.val(); 
$scope.$apply(function() { 
$scope.tanggal = snapshot; }); 
console.log($scope.tanggal); 
myAfterFunction(); //here i call the function 
}) 

function myAfterFunction(){ 
console.log($scope.tanggal); // The function is triggered after called in snapshot function this time $scope.tanggal has value from firebase 
}
```